# Save vs2010 Test Results Columns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

How can I set the default column display of the Test Results window in vs2010? With each new project, I find it necessary to add a column to the display. This also happens from time to time with an existing project. What I want is to not have to do this again.

Is there a way to specify the default columns to be displayed for current and future projects?

Before:
[image: Picture with default columns.]

After:
[image: Picture with correct columns.]

Comment: Post feature requests to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666162/save-vs2010-test-results-columns#details